# How to hide the null date[0001-01-01T00:00:00] value in view?

Tags: html, angular

[image: View]

In my manager, I set the null value to date.but in view it shows the some value.I need to hide that date value.I tried if the created date is null, I showed empty data.but it comes with some value

**Html:**

```
<ng-template #tmplt>
    <tr *ngFor="let manage of managecontent; let i =index">
        <td>{{manage.CategorytypeName}}</td>
        <td>{{manage.CreatedBy}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="manage.CreatedDate!=null">{{manage.CreatedDate}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="manage.CreatedDate == null"></td>
        <td *ngIf="manage.DocumentDetails!=null">{{manage.DocumentDetails.DocName}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="manage.DocumentDetails==null"></td>
        <td>
            <app-file-upload [documentModel]="manage.DocumentDetails" [isMultipleFile]="true" [model]="manage" (emitterFile)="fileSelect($event)"></app-file-upload>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: How do you set `null` to the date? What kind of class do you use for `CreatedDate`?

Comment: i am using DateTime.Now..simply I assigned the null value.For Example createdDate =null;

Comment: Is this data coming from a database? Or from another language? Maybe there the `null` value is set to `[0001-01-01T00:00:00]` by default. Maybe you can change that there to be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the *ngIf like this.

```
<td *ngIf="!manage.CreatedDate">{{manage.CreatedDate}}</td>
```

Second, you should use timestamps or date objects for your dates. Not strings.

Third, once you manage your dates with objects or timestamps, you can test them easily : either they have the value `null`, or their value is the start of the Unix time (maning the timestamp would be equal to zero). In both cases, those are **falsy** values, that you can test as I told you in the first point of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
<td *ngIf="!manage.CreatedDate; else elseBlock">{{manage.CreatedDate}}</td>
<ng-template #elseBlock> - </ng-template>
```